# Is using static variable in mult thread application safe?

Tags: c#

I have a multi thread application that runs a method  which contains `public static variable`.
I want to know this `public static variable` is separate for each thread or not.
is it value can be changed by other thread?

Comment: Are you concerned with data integrity (e.g. corruption of an object state), or with a logical race condition? If the former, you don't always have to use synchronization (i.e. a `lock` statement), if access to your variable type access is atomic (e.g. it is a bool, 32-bit int, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not thread safe.

`static` variables live for the life of an `AppDomain`. Unless it is `const` or `readonly` .. then they can be mutated by any thread within your application.

Comment: What about using static methods in a multi thread application?

Comment: That makes no difference. `static` != thread safe.

Comment: What about using `tuple` to return multiple values?

Comment: You should look up what thread safety is.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the *static variable* to be *separate* for each tread use `TreadLocal<T>` class. e.g. let's have `Random` (which is *not thread safe by default*) to be thread safe:

```
  public class Sample {
    private static ThreadLocal<Random> s_Generator = new ThreadLocal<Random>(
       () => new Random());

    public static Random Generator {
      get {
        return s_Generator.Value;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`static` variables are shared by all application threads. In fact, this is one way of sharing state between threads.

You can make a static variable thread-local (i.e. each thread will have a single, separate copy of the variable) by decorating it with the [`ThreadStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute. For example:

```
class WithThreadStatic
{
    [ThreadStatic] 
    public static bool IsSad = true;
}
```